# specifying output types for functions in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

I have this function

```
def only_str() -> str:
    return None

print(only_str())
```

Although **None** is not `str` but it's not giving me errors and everything works!

Why is that?

How can I specify output type for functions?

Comment: Python doesn't support strict typing natively, but you should probably look at an editor with type checking to give warnings or find an alternative interpreter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python doesn't actually enforce typehints. They're useful for documentation and linting. To enforce, you'll need to check with a type checker like [mypy](http://mypy-lang.org/).

```
# test.py
def foo(i: int) -> str:
    return str(i)

def bar(i: int) -> str:
    return None


print(foo(1), bar(1))
```

When I run `python test.py` I get `1 None`

When I run `mypy test.py` I get this:

```
error: Incompatible return value type (got "None", expected "str")
```